# How to Convert The bayerrg8 data to Rgb (or any colored) data In Qt?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, rgb

I tried the convertToFormat function here is my code of that.

```
QImage image((unsigned char*)GCamera.Frames[Index].ImageBuffer,1360,1024,QImage::Format_Indexed8);
image = image.convertToFormat(QImage::Format_RGB888);
buffer = QPixmap::fromImage(image);
label->setPixmap(buffer);
label->show();
```

But the above code shows only black and white video I also tried those color_table and then setpixel etc. but couldn't set them clearly.
Please let me some way to do this in Qt?

Comment: Qt has limited colorspace support. You should use a separate library to convert to rgb. The framework which provide the original data doesn't have a Bayer-rgb888 conversion?

Comment: okay so what are my options? my camera (http://www.alliedvisiontec.com/fileadmin/content/PDF/Products/Technical_Manual/GC_Series/700034A_-_GC1380H_User_Manual.pdf)gives Mono8,Mono16,bayer8,bayer16,Rgb24,Bgr24,Yuv411,Yuv422,Yuv444,Rgba32,Bgra32,Rgb48,Mono12packed,bayer12Packed formats and Qt has Format_Mono,Format_MonoLSB,Format_Indexed8,Format_RGB32,Format_ARGB32,Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied,Format_RGB16,Format_ARGB8565_Premultiplied,Format_RGB666,Format_ARGB6666_Premultiplied,Format_RGB555,Format_ARGB8555_Premultiplied,Format_RGB888,Format_RGB444,Format_ARGB4444_Premultiplied, these formats.

Comment: I am not going to read 32 pages of docs. By it seems your camera is in bayer mode, you can use rgb\bgr modes instead. Then no conversion needed

Comment: lol I just put that link for reference but the useful part I wrote. anyway I have tried taking the data at rgb24 format and in qt side I used RGB888 format for display but that is just not working totally !!! it will show black screen, frame completed zero but not working. :(

Comment: can you show the code for the other alternative too? because in any case you should not use `QImage::Format_Indexed8` to construct the image object.